# I had to take an extended medical leave. How do I report this absence of time on my résumé?

Tags: resume

I am a 2nd year college student. After my first year of college, I unfortunately had a musculoskeletal problem for nearly 6 years that impaired basic functioning. I had to take extended medical leave, but I managed to resolve the problem and am back in school now. I just took my first semester of classes and everything is back in order seemingly :D  But there is obviously a gap in my résumé, a considerable period of time unaccounted for due to the problem I had.

How should I write this into my résumé?

Comment: Is there something from before your time in college that you want to list on your resume, or is college the earliest entry?

Answer (score 0):

Don't write it it into your resume at all. Simply list the dates of your education (when you started, when you graduated once that time comes), and any employment that needs to be put on the resume.

If you're asked about it, just say "I had to take time to address personal matters, but that's all behind me now and I'm picking up where I left off." Don't reveal that it was a medical problem, and don't make up another story to cover for it. It was a personal matter, and that's all anyone needs to know.

Comment: It's politically correct these days to admit health challenges. _Personal matters_ can sometimes be interpreted as though you're hiding something. "I had to take some time away from school due to some health challenges. I'm all better now, and ready to get going again."

Answer (score 0):

For schooling just put the end date that you completed the program. For workplaces put the start and end date, for school projects don't put a date or put the term you did the project in.

It's also a good idea to talk to recruiters or head hunters and look at how they layout resumes. It is, afterall, what they do for a living

**Example:**

**Some Company: high performance kitten tracing software** - Orlando, FL.

Projects: Kitten Tracer 2.0 - Android App.

Lead Android Developer, Jan. 2014 to Jun. 2015

- Created... with... etc...
- Designed...

**SOME UNIVERSITY** - Houston, TX.

Projects: First iOS App. - iOS App.

Lead iOS Developer, Term 1

- Created... with... etc...
- Implemented... using...

*Education*

---

SOME UNIVERSITY -- Houston, TX | BS in Computer Science, Emphasis on Robots, 2015

. Salutatorian, perfect attendance, ect...